# How to group two dictionary items into one list entry from another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
l1 = [{'_id': 0, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1},
      {'_id': 1, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'two', 'des': 2},
      {'_id': 2, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1},
      {'_id': 3, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'five', 'des': 5}]

l2 = [{'g_id': 0, 'type': 'group1', 'name': 'first',},
      {'g_id': 1, 'type': 'group2', 'name': 'second'},]
```

How do I group items like this? Referring to the previous two pieces of data, extract two items from list1 and group them with list2?

```
group_result = [{'g_id': 0, 'type': 'group1', 'name': 'first',
                'group':[{'_id': 0, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1},
                         {'_id': 1, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'two', 'des': 2}]},
                {'g_id': 1, 'type': 'group1', 'name': 'first',
                'group':[{'_id': 2, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1},
                         {'_id': 3, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'five', 'des': 5}]}]
```

Comment: How do you know which items in `l1` belong with each item in `l2`?

Comment: I mean list1 will pull out two at a time and group it with one of the items in list2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal list comprehension will be suffice for this

```
group_result=[ {**l2[i], **{"group": l1[2*i: (2*i)+2]}} for i in range(0, len(l2))]
```

OUTPUT

```
[{'g_id': 0,
  'type': 'group1',
  'name': 'first',
  'group': [{'_id': 0, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1},
   {'_id': 1, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'two', 'des': 2}]},
 {'g_id': 1,
  'type': 'group2',
  'name': 'second',
  'group': [{'_id': 2, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1},
   {'_id': 3, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'five', 'des': 5}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I hope these methods will help other users. can fix this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Python >= 3.9, you can use [`dict` concatenation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/) (assuming that `len(l1)` is two times `len(l2)`):

```py
[grp | {'group': grp_ids}
 for grp, grp_ids in zip(l2, [l1[i*2:(i+1)*2] for i in range(len(l2))])]
```

The result is:

```bash
[{'g_id': 0, 'type': 'group1', 'name': 'first', 'group': [{'_id': 0, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1}, {'_id': 1, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'two', 'des': 2}]}, {'g_id': 1, 'type': 'group2', 'name': 'second', 'group': [{'_id': 2, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'one', 'des': 1}, {'_id': 3, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'five', 'des': 5}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I hope these methods will help other users. can fix this problem. :)